# How to change the value at a user inputted row and column of a 2d C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

In my program, i'm working on a function that gets user inputted  row, column, and new value which will replace the old value in the same index of a 2d array of equal dimensions that were set to a constant int 5. (it's a square)  Here's what i tried to do:

```
cout << "Input the row, the column, and new value: " << endl;
    cin >> changeR >> changeC >> newval;

    Sqarr[changeR, changeC] = newval;
```

i got an error saying that my expression must be a modifiable value.

Is my strategy wrong? can I not do this to a 2d array?

Comment: An array of arrays in C++ (or C) is indexed as `Squar[changeR][changeC] = ...`. Your code is trying to assign to essentially `Squar[changeC] = ...`. See the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) to better understand what you actually doing.

Comment: Read your notes again.  A 2D array in C++ is accessed using `[x] [y]`, not `[x, y]`.

Answer (score 2):

You simply used the incorrect syntax. While what you did works for other languages, in C/C++ it has a different meaning:

```
Sqarr[changeR, changeC] = newval;
```

doesn't do what it does in other languages. What you want is:

```
Sqarr[changeR][changeC] = newval;
```

The top statement uses C's "comma" operator, which evaluates the first value (`changeR`), then evaluates the second value (`changeC`) and simply returns the second value. That would only index the row of `Sqarr`, which you cannot assign `newval` to.

The bottom one says "get the `changeR` row of `Sqarr`, and then index the `changeC` column out of that."

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax. 
It must be:

```
array[row][col] = value;
```

And i would check array indexes.

```
cin >> row >> col >> new_value; 
if((row > 0 && row < MAX_ROWS_COUNT) && (col > 0 && col < MAX_COLS_COUNT)) 
{
    array[row][col] = new_value; 
}
```